# jQuery validate addmethod always returning true

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've added a username check available function to my jquery validate page.  If I look at the response from the remote function in Firebug I see the correct response - TRUE or FALSE.  Likewise if I add an alert() in the response msg it shows up correct.  However, using the code below - the addmethod always returns TRUE back.

```
$.validator.addMethod('usernamecheck',function(username) {
    var postURL = [url to remote function]
    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        data: "username=" + username,
        url: postURL,
            success: function(msg) {
                result = (msg=='FALSE') ? false : true;
            }
    });
    return result;
}, '');
```

I've verified the function is returning boolean true or false only but I'm stumped as to why result returns `true` every time.

SOLVED

I switched the CFC to make sure it was set to return boolean and plain:

```
<cffunction name="checkUsernameRemote" access="remote" returntype="boolean" output="no" returnformat="plain">
```

Then did a Serialize JSON on my return value:

```
<cfset LOCAL.result = SerializeJSON(LOCAL.result)/>      
<cfreturn LOCAL.result />
```

In my jQuery I got rid of the addMethod() and moved it into a remote rule:

```
username: {
    required: true,
    rangelength: [4,50],
    remote: {
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        url: compath + "/rmtUserCFC.cfc?method=checkUsernameRemote&returnformat=json",
        type: "post"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your return inside of the `success` function.

```
success: function(msg) {
          return (msg=='FALSE') ? false : true;
      }
```

Comment: Doing that returns false every time.  If I put an alert(msg); above return I am getting TRUE or FALSE back from the function - nothing else.

Comment: What does your underlying PHP script look like? Is it echoing the string "FALSE" as expected, when false, in your script?

Comment: using output directly from the function, as well as firebug show that the function correctly returns true / false based on the username check.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the CFC to make sure it was set to return Boolean and plain:

```
<cffunction name="checkUsernameRemote" access="remote" returntype="boolean" output="no" returnformat="plain">
```

Then did a Serialize JSON on my return value:

```
<cfset LOCAL.result = SerializeJSON(LOCAL.result)/>      
<cfreturn LOCAL.result />
```

In my jQuery I got rid of the addMethod() and moved it into a remote rule:

```
username: {
required: true,
rangelength: [4,50],
remote: {
    url: compath + "/rmtUserCFC.cfc?method=checkUsernameRemote&returnformat=json",
    type: "post"
  }
},
```